# How to archive and unarchive images in iphone

Tags: iphone, uiimage, bluetooth, nsdata

I am coding an iPhone application where images are transferred from one iPhone to another using Bluetooth.  How do I archive an image and send it to another iPhone, then un-archive the image back?  Archiving the image directly using NSKeyedarchiver doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn UIImage objects into NSData representations using the [Image Manipulation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006894-CH3-SW28) function `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` or `UIImagePNGRepresentation`.

You can turn the NSData representation into a UIImage using the UIImage convenience method [imageWithData:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006890-CH3-SW13) or initializer [initWithData:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006890-CH3-SW17).